# Can not change .Net Framework to 6.0 in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: frameworks

Hey so I have Visual Studio 2022, I installed the .NET Framework 6.0.1 SDK manually from the microsoft website, If I check the Visual Studio Installer the .NET 6.0 Runtime is checked (means it is installed).

But I am neither able to retarget my existing Projects to 6.0, neither create a new Project for 6.0. The .NET Framework 6.0 simply doesn't appear in the dropdown selection.

I found another thread which had the same issue but nothing worked for me.

I've read that you can change the Targetframework editing the .csproj file with Notepad, I tried that but at start it told me I don't have the framework installed and either need to downgrade to 4.8 or install 6.0.1.

I've restarted and reinstalled Visual Studio several times now, same with my Computer.
What the heck is wrong here?